# Accessing VB.Net functions from Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am trying to get a VB.Net DLL function exposed as a COM to work in Excel.  The post [Accessing .NET functions exposed as COM in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996617/accessing-net-function-exposed-as-com-in-excel) was very helpful. I was able to successfully register the dll and tlb files.

The class object I created is visible to Excel, but its member is not. I am working in Windows 7-64 bit with Office 2010-32 bit.  I compiled the dll for x86.

Here is the code

```
Namespace PRISMTest
    Public Class Test
        Public ReadOnly Property CheckExcelVersion As Integer
            Get
                Return 15
            End Get
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And what I see in the Excel Object Browser.  Any ideas?

[image: Object Browser]

Comment: In the future, please post any image files as .PNG and not JPEG. PNG is a lot smaller, which matters to people reading on mobile devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to add the following code: