# How to convert vba to executable (.exe) file

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, executable

I made an Excel macro VBA script for the office, and it runs perfectly fine, but I got a request to convert it to an executable .exe file.

I use a Mac and there are many older posts that came up on Google that says to convert it to .vbs and .vb/.vbs (not sure the difference, didn't grow up in Windows) and add a script to just open the Excel application and run my VBA script.

What is the easiest way for me to do that? And is it possible for me to do it in the Mac environment or can it only be done in Windows?

I know that the Microsoft stack was pretty proprietary back in the days, but it's opened up in recent years so I just want to see if there are newer developments, hence solutions that are not in the older posts.

Thanks!

Comment: VBA is an interpreted language, not a compiled language, if you want an exe then use VB instead.  A .vb file is a visual basic file while a .vbs is a visual basic script file.

Comment: @NickA VBS must be a VBScript file in this context.

Comment: If you want an exe you will have to convert your code into either a VB6 project (straightforward) or a VB.NET solution (not necessarily straightforward). Neither will work on a MAC.

Comment: @GSerg If I do manage to get my hands on a Window, could you give me an overview of how to do that in VB6? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @BenWong http://stackoverflow.com/q/2041363/11683

Comment: There are options to convert but can I ask why you need to convert to an executable file? (not that I'm suggesting that its not a good idea). You can setup Excel so that it appears to work like an executable. So when it starts all you see is the Forms and not Excel sheets. Maybe an easier option